# LPAD function errors when used in WITH variable in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, lpad

Can you tell me why this is throwing an error in Redshift?

```
WITH Testing_PADDING AS (SELECT '12345678' AS column1)
SELECT LPAD(column1, 9,'0') FROM Testing_PADDING;
```

Here is the error I receive:

"Invalid operation: failed to find conversion function from "unknown" to text;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift can't determine data type from the context, so you need to explicitly set it

```sql
WITH Testing_PADDING AS (SELECT '12345678'::text AS column1)
SELECT
    LPAD(column1, 9, '0')
FROM Testing_PADDING;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that one of your strings isn't being seen as text - likely the column1 text.  (Sorry don't have a cluster up not to test)

Try:

```
WITH Testing_PADDING AS (SELECT '12345678'::text AS column1)
SELECT LPAD(column1, 9,'0'::text) FROM Testing_PADDING;
```